# if statement without the inner scope?

Tags: c++, variables, if-statement, scope

Afaik, every pair of `{ }` in the code creates a new scope. Even if it's used just for the sake of it without any `if`, `for`, function or other statement that demands it:

```
void myFun(void)
{
    int a;
    {
        int local;
    }
}
```

I started wondering - when the `if` statement is written without using the braces (with 1-line body) does it still create a new scope?

```
voidmyFun(int a)
{
    int b;
    if (a == 1)
        int tmp;   // is this one local to if?
    else
        int tmp2;   // or this one?
    b = 2;   // could I use tmp here?
}
```

Comment: yes, they're local to their `if` part

Comment: "// could I use tmp here" - Did you *try* to? What happened, and did it support or squelch your thoughts on your first two inquiries?

Comment: No, I didn't. One, because right now I don't even have an environment on which I could test it and two, because testing like that doesn't tell the whole truth - it might work in my case and not in others and doesn't give me reasons why. Plus, I think it might be a useful question for other users of SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

N4140 [stmt.select]/1 reads:

> The substatement in a *selection-statement* (each substatement, in the `else` form of the `if` statement) implicitly defines a block scope

So, the code

```
if (a == 1)
    int tmp;   // is this one local to if?
else
    int tmp2;   // or this one?
```

is equivalent to

```
if (a == 1)
{
    int tmp;   // yes, this one is local to if
}
else
{
    int tmp2;   // and this one as well
}
```

Comment: Is that quote from the language standard maybe? You labeled it but it seems to have a type-o.

Comment: @NPS yes, it's from N4140. In the previous standards it's more or less the same. And I don't see any typos here.

Comment: I thought it was some kind of an SO tag but guess it's not. :P Nvm.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, even if the if and for do not have `{}`, the variables declared in it are local to it.

So, if you try something like

```
if ( something )
    int a = 3;
std::cout << a;  // there is no other identifier called a in your program
```

it will not compile, because it is the same as

```
if ( something )
{
    int a = 3;
}
std::cout << a;
```

and you will get a variable not declared in this scope error.

So,

```
voidmyFun(int a)
{
    int b;
    if (a == 1)
        int tmp;   // is this one local to if?   Ans:-  Yes
    else
        int tmp2;   // or this one?          Ans:- It is local to else block
    b = 2;   // could I use tmp here?      Ans:-  No
}
```

So, the variable inside the `else` ( `tmp2` ) is local to `else` and not to `if`.

Answer (score 2):

In short - yes. It's a single line scope.

In other words, writing:

```
if (someCondition) 
    int i = 7;
```

Is identical, scope-wise, to writing:

```
if (someCondition) 
{
    int i = 7;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes! `tmp` are local to `if` and `tmp2` is local to `else`. If you try using `tmp` or `temp2` outside, you should get variable not defined error. It is because,

```
if(<condition>) <my-statment> 
if(<condition>) 
{ 
  <my-statment> 
}
```

For compiler, both of them are equal.

Comment: nice: testing whether the variable is defined will close the whole discussion once and for all.